# How can I insert content using javascript as raw html in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<p id="selfText-@item.ThreadID">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
      GetSelfText('@item.ThreadID'); 
    });
  </script>
</p>

function GetSelfText(thingId) { 
  $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/playitforward/comments/" + thingId + "/.json?jsonp=?",
            { id: thingId }, 
            function (data) { 
              $("#selfText-" + thingId).html(data[0].data.children[0].data.selftext_html) 
            }) 
}
```

Right now it's encoding the html and wrapping the html in quotations. I need it to be raw html. I also am trying to use a JQuery Expander and it's not working for ajax inserted content.

So I need to solve 2 problems. Insert the returned data as raw html and make the expander plugin work with ajax inserted content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding happens from the reddit api.

Try

```
function (data) { 
    var tempHtml = $('<div/>').html( data[0].data.children[0].data.selftext_html ).text();
    $("#selfText-" + thingId).html( tempHtml ) ;
}
```

as the callback method..

Comment: @sevenalive, glad it worked.. for the expander you might want to describe the issue in more detail, and post related code as well (*perhaps a new question is better*)